# Make the readline method of Python recognize both end-of-line variations?

Tags: python

I am writing a Python file that needs to read in several files of different types.  I am reading the files in line by line with the traditional `for line in f` after using `f = open("file.txt", "r")`.

This doesn't seem to be working for all files.  My guess is some files end with different encodings (such as \r\n versus just \r).  I can read the whole file in and do a string split on \r, but that is hugely costly and I'd rather not.  Is there a way to make the readline method of Python recognize both end-of-line variations?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use the universal newline support -- see http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#open

> In addition to the standard fopen()
>   values mode may be 'U' or 'rU'. Python
>   is usually built with universal
>   newline support; supplying 'U' opens
>   the file as a text file, but lines may
>   be terminated by any of the following:
>   the Unix end-of-line convention '\n',
>   the Macintosh convention '\r', or the
>   Windows convention '\r\n'. All of
>   these external representations are
>   seen as '\n' by the Python program. If
>   Python is built without universal
>   newline support a mode with 'U' is the
>   same as normal text mode. Note that
>   file objects so opened also have an
>   attribute called newlines which has a
>   value of None (if no newlines have yet
>   been seen), '\n', '\r', '\r\n', or a
>   tuple containing all the newline types
>   seen.

Comment: Of course, the "Macintosh" convention of terminating line ends with '\r' (ASCII 13, CR) was also used by nearly every 8-bit microcomputer prior to the Macintosh, including the Apple II, Commodore, and Atari.

Comment: See my answer for a question about your answer.

Comment: Great tip. Interestingly, I was able to open a file in `rUb` mode, which allowed me to do a `infile.readline()` that handle lines universally (so I could throw away a header), while also allowing file to be read as binary for `shutil.copyfileobj(infile, outfile)` to allow me to merge my files.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use a generator approach to read the lines by yourself and ignore any EOL characters:

```
def readlines(f):
    line = []
    while True:
        s = f.read(1)
        if len(s) == 0:
            if len(line) > 0:
                yield line
            return
        if s in ('\r','\n'):
            if len(line) > 0:
                yield line
            line = []
        else:
            line.append(s)

for line in readlines(yourfile):
    # ...
```

Comment: Oops, just noticed bgporter's post - if there's a native support for that, then apparently you won't need this generator. :)

Comment: Your solution discards blank lines (e.g. `\n\n` or `\r\n\r\n`), yields character lists instead of strings, and will run really slowly due to reading a character at a time without buffering.  I'm not sure working with character lists instead of strings improves performance either.