# python parse plain text file with ^M carriage returns

Tags: python, file, parsing, carriage-return

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Make the readline method of Python recognize both end-of-line variations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4158645/make-the-readline-method-of-python-recognize-both-end-of-line-variations)

Hello, I have a plain text file that uses ^M as carriage returns. In my OSX text editors it appears well formatted with spaces, but in vi it shows as one line with ^M interspaced throughout the file.

Python also only sees this file as one long line, but I need it to view the ^M as a carriage return instead of ignoring it. (When python prints out this file, the ^M are not visible.) I would like to use readLines() and then add new lines between the list elements.

I've seen various flags about opening things in python with binary mode but these are not giving me the desired results.

Comment: It makes me mad that line endings *still* waste so much time.

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4158645/make-the-readline-method-of-python-recognize-both-end-of-line-variations ?

Comment: Yes, an answer on that page did help solve my problem. (not the user approved answer but it worked)

Answer (score 0):

They can be safely removed.  If you're using vi you can remove all extraneous visible `^M` characters by issuing the following command (in command mode of course):

```
%s[enter]
```

(Actually hit the <kbd>enter</kbd> key, don't type that in!)